# Unable to call an API and get respective output in Python

Tags: python, api

I am new to python and I am trying to call an API and get output, however, I am running into the following error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position
>   2: invalid start byte

The code I have written thus far is as follows:

```
import requests
file = open("NLPData/testimg.png")
payload = {file}
response = requests.get("http://sampleapi.com/get", params=payload)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: `{file}` creates set with single element. What do you want to send to this API? Normally files should be sent using POST or PUT.

Comment: PNG files are binary. Http GET params are usually text. Is the API really expecting a binary blob as a param?

Comment: In addition to what other commenters have said, I would recommend using a context manager to handle that file object.